# How can I configure Jetbrains DataSpell to work on a notebook which is connected to Dataproc cluster?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-dataproc, dataspell

I have a Dataproc cluster in Google cloud, and instead of using the Google dataproc jupyter notebook on web, is there anyway we can connect DataSpell to run jobs on that cluster?

Thanks.